# Difference between performing INSERT INTO vs Using MERGE INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I started working on a project that already has some scripts running and while I was looking some of the scripts that have already been done I encountered an scenario that looks something like this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Persons
SELECT PersonId = 1, Firstname = 'Joaquin', LastName = 'Alvarez'
INTO #Persons
DECLARE @inserted table (PersonId INT, Firstname VARCHAR(50), Lastname VARCHAR(50))

MERGE INTO dbo.Persons P USING #Persons TP ON 1 = 0 -- Forcing mismatch
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT 
        (
             PersonId,
             Firstname,
             Lastname
        )
        VALUES 
        (
             TP.PersonId,
             TP.Firstname,
             TP.LastName
        )

OUTPUT INSERTED.PersonId, INSERTED.Firstname, INSERTED.LastName
INTO @inserted;
```

My Question here is **why they would use the merge into and force the mismatch just to perform an insert**, they could have done the same without it with something like this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Persons
SELECT PersonId = 1, Firstname = 'Joaquin', LastName = 'Alvarez'
INTO #Persons
DECLARE @inserted table (PersonId INT, Firstname VARCHAR(50), Lastname VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Persons
OUTPUT INSERTED.PersonId, INSERTED.Firstname, INSERTED.LastName
INTO @inserted
VALUES (1, 'Joaquin', 'Alvarez')
```

The first option is faster than the last one? or they're bot the same? This is the first time I see the merge into used this way.

Comment: I, personally, don't see the need for the `MERGE` here. *If*, however, the `MERGE` was outputting columns (in the `OUTPUT` clause) from objects other than  `inserted`, it *would* make sense, but as it stands as the `MERGE` could be replicated with a `INSERT`. Perhaps it did in the past, or was meant to, and then didn't (and thus the `MERGE` statement was left). The only person who can truly answer why the wrote the above the way they did would be the person who wrote it.

Comment: Questions of the form "what was person X thinking when.." are not on topic for SO, sorry!

Comment: There is simply NO GOOD REASON to create and populate a temp table in this script, regardless of whether MERGE or INSERT is used. That alone tells me that the writer of this code tends to blindly apply patterns.

Comment: @MatBailie Hey, I deleted it because I thought that as you mention, the question was due to a silly misstake and doesn't bring much value to have that kind of questions lying around SO. It's not like I dont appreciate the effort Gordon put into looking at my question, I just thought that due to the stupid nature of the question It will be closed sooner than later. Try to don't assume what people think and chill of a bit maybe?

Comment: @Joaquín That's not how Stack Overflow works.  Else there would be no rep scores, no upvotes, etc.  Asking a question then deleting it when it's answered is simply rude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would really need to ask the person who wrote the code.  But I can think of two and a half reasons.

The first is that the original code was both an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` so the author used `MERGE` to handle the code.  As the code was tested or as requirements changed, the person who wrote it realized that the `UPDATE` was not needed, but left the `MERGE`.

The half reason is that someone wrote the code expecting `UPDATE`s to be needed over time, so tried to future-proof the code.

The second reason is that the author may simply prefer `MERGE`s over `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s because it is one statement that is more powerful than either of those individually.  So, they simply always use `MERGE`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I was wondering because Im not that experienced and  believed that maybe the MERGE was faster for some reason.

Comment: Merge should really be avoided in favor of sticking with update and insert; it has many bugs and edge-cases, many of which MS will not fix.

Answer (score 2):

There are **two big differences** I can think of that may have caused the query to be written as `MERGE`:

**1. `MERGE` allows column references in the `OUTPUT` clause that are not in the `inserted` table.** Admittedly, the current query does not have that, but it is possible that other references were originally there or intended to be added.

**2. Halloween Protection is much more efficient on `MERGE`.**
Paul White [goes into detail in his excellent article](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/sql-plan/halloween-problem-part-3) on this, but basically, when executing a `INSERT/WHERE NOT EXISTS`, this forces the optimizer to add a Table Spool to ensure correct results. A `MERGE` usually does not require this, as the optimizer can see what you are trying to do: fill the empty holes in the primary key.

I note that your query does not have a `NOT EXISTS` semantic, but again, it is possible that it was intended ast some point to have it.

---

As you state, `#Person` is **entirely pointless** here. Even with `MERGE` you can still do that from a constructed table, eg.

```sql
MERGE INTO dbo.Persons P
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'Joaquin', 'Alvarez') ) AS v(PersonId, Firstname, LastName)
) TP ON 1 = 0 -- Forcing mismatch
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (PersonId, Firstname, Lastname)
        VALUES (TP.PersonId, TP.Firstname, TP.LastName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.PersonId, INSERTED.Firstname, INSERTED.LastName
INTO @inserted;
```