# SQL Insert Using a user defined table into two table with the second joining onto the first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a type table that contains 3 values

1. An ID
2. A String value
3. And a int

The first table that i insert into takes only the string value

The second table is where my question lies
I need to insert into it the ID in the type table, the int and finally the corolating ID from the first table

So Table one would look like this after the import

| Table1ID | String |
| --- | --- |
| Table1ID1 | String1 |
| Table1ID2 | String2 |

And table 2 after the import

| Table2ID | IDFromType | Table2ID | IntFromType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table2ID1 | IDFromType1 | Table1ID1 | IntFromType1 |
| Table2ID2 | IDFromType2 | Table1ID2 | IntFromType2 |

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TYPE AS TABLE` statements.

Comment: Do not post image pls, write out your table structure

Comment: So what's your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How would i import the ID of the first table into the second

Comment: @Nikita See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have something like this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.PuppyType AS TABLE (
    PuppyId    int          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name       nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BarkVolume int          NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Doggos (
    DoggoId       int          NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SourcePuppyId int              NULL,
    Name          nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.BarkMeasurements (
    MeasurementId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    DoggoId       int NOT NULL,
    BarkVolume    int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Barks_to_Doggos FOREIGN KEY ( DoggoId ) REFERENCES dbo.Doggos ( DoggoId )
);
```

Your `PROCEDURE` should look like this (there's [a lot of boilerplate for transactions and error-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa)...):

- Use a `TRY` block with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` + `COMMIT TRANSACTION` to ensure the operation is atomic: so if it fails then everything will be rolled-back and you won't have incomplete data in your database.
- Use the `OUTPUT` clause of DML (redirected to a local table-variable) to capture newly generated `IDENTITY` values and reuse them for mapping and inserting into additional tables.

  - Unfortunately you cannot use the (simpler) `INSERT INTO x` statement to insert into the first table because its `OUTPUT` statement only lets you output data that ended up in the `x` table [but for some reason the `MERGE` statement's `OUTPUT` clause **does** let you `OUTPUT` additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66530817/159145).
- So use `MERGE INTO` with an *always-false* match condition (`ON 1 = 0`) to force an `INSERT`-only `MERGE` and `OUTPUT` the inserted data to a table-variable `@dboPuppiesInsertOutput`.
- Then for the second table you can use a simpler `INSERT INTO x ( y, z ) SELECT y, z FROM a INNER JOIN @dboPuppiesInsertOutput` statement.

  - You can add an `OUTPUT` clause to this too to return *that* inserted data to the SQL Server client if you like.

Like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPuppyData
    @puppies dbo.PuppyType READONLY
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION insertPuppiesTxn;

    --

    DECLARE @dboPuppiesInsertOutput TABLE (
        PuppyId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        DoggoId int NOT NULL
    );

    -- Need to use MERGE because INSERT doesn't let you OUTPUT extra data.
    -- Also need HOLDLOCK: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187776/merge-deadlocking-prevention

    MERGE INTO dbo.Doggos WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS tgt
    USING @puppies AS src ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ( SourcePuppyId, "Name" )
        VALUES ( src.PuppyId, src."Name" )
    OUTPUT
        src.PuppyId,
        inserted.DoggoId
        INTO @dboPuppiesInsertOutput;

    -- We can use INSERT here as we don't need MERGE's more powerful OUTPUT clause:
    INSERT INTO dbo.BarkMeasurements ( DoggoId, BarkVolume )
    SELECT
        m.DoggoId,
        p.BarkVolume
    FROM
        @puppies AS p
        INNER JOIN @dboPuppiesInsertOutput AS m ON p.PuppyId = m.PuppyId;

    --

    COMMIT TRANSACTION insertPuppiesTxn;

    RETURN 0;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT >= 1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION insertPuppiesTxn;

    THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Comment: `BEGIN CATCH` is unnecessary if all you are doing is rolling back and rethrowing: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` deals with that anyway. Equally `RETURN 0;` is unnecessary, that's the default

Comment: @Charlieface You are correct. In my defense though I have this saved in my SSDT+SSMS  New Procedure item-template and because (me, at least) often quickly iterate procedure designs it's less hassle overall to have a (slightly redundant, but harmless) `CATCH` - but it's handy for the 50%-of-the-time I need to add-or-remove custom error handling logic, etc without needing to comment-out all the `BEGIN/END TRY/CATCH` block markers. SQL is not an ergonomic language :(